# How to get a single total column in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a column for total quantity but crystal reports generates the quantity values in more than  one column.

6

9

126

221 is what I need.

Comment: Not a very clear question. Can you post up your report definition.

Comment: ok,  
  
I uploaded my report and noted my problem on it. Here is the link:

Comment: ok,  
  
I uploaded my report and noted my problem on it. Here is the link:https://rapidshare.com/files/1863698845/cr.rar  
  
Thanks,

Comment: Sorry I can't open it as I'm on VS12 / win8 now and have problems. Hopefully someone else can help

Comment: That's ok Dave, thank you for your efforts.

Comment: I've re-tagged with crystal-reports to hopefully get more exposure.

Answer (score 0):

You can add just a formula to your column. After googling just a while i found this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567625/add-total-per-row-and-column-in-crystal-reports-without-crosstab). 
Hope it helps